# Vitamio VideView crashes

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, vitamio

I'm trying to play stream video in my app using Vitamio VideoView.
I've downloaded vitamio demo app and it worked fine with my url. But when I'm trying to use it in my app it crashes after "mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));"

```
 public void play ()
 {      
    LinearLayout VideoView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoview);       
    VideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String path = "here is my url"; 

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view1);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            // optional need Vitamio 4.0
            //mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });

 }
```

This is layout for my videoview in main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/videoview"    
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   android:visibility="gone">

<io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout>
```

LogCat shows:

```
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): Error loading libs
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:771): library "nulllibstlport_shared.so" not found
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:340)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at java.lang.System.load(System.java:507)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:100)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:78)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:221)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.access$29(VideoView.java:209)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView$9.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:461)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
 04-12 20:00:00.241: E/Vitamio(16177): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native      Method)
```

Comment: You are not really trying to parse "here is my url", are you? What is the error you get?

Comment: Of course not :) I have link for stream video

Comment: Are you testing on a device or an emulator?

Comment: Also see if this thread helps: https://bbs.vitamio.org/topics/59?locale=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem! :)

First of all I've added to the manifest

```
 <activity
    android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

And this to my onCreate():

```
     new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        //              mPD = new ProgressDialog(InitActivity.this);
        //              mPD.setCancelable(false);
        //      PD.setMessage(getString(R.string.vitamio_init_decoders));
        //              mPD.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
            return Vitamio.initialize(MyMapActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean inited) {
        //              if (inited) {
        //                  uiHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        //              }
        }

    }.execute();
```